# Compose - DropDownMenu is causing unwanted recomposition

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, compose-recomposition

This is the composable hierarchy in my app:

```
HorizontalPager
↪LazyVerticalGrid
 ↪PostItem
  ↪AsyncImage
   DropdownMenu
   ↪DropdownMenuItem
```

When swiping the `HorizontalPager` the `AsyncImage` inside my PostItem's are recomposing.
Removing the `DropdownMenu` fixes this and the PostItem is no longe recomposing and gives the wanted behavior.

The problem is that I have huge FPS drops when swiping through the `HorizontalPager`.
Why is `DropdownMenu` causing a recomposition when swiping the `HorizontalPager`?

```
var showMenu by remember { mutableStateOf(false) }
        DropdownMenu(
            expanded = showMenu,
            onDismissRequest = { showMenu = false }) {
            DropdownMenuItem(onClick = {

            }) {
                Text(text = "Share")
            }
    
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, without seeing more code showing the rest of the structure, it's hard to say for sure what your problem is here.

A likely answer is that you haven't split up your Composable function enough. Something the docs hardly talk about is that the `content` portion of a lot of the built-in Composeables are `inline functions` which means that if the content recomposes the parent will as well. This is the most simple example of this I can give.

```
@Composable
fun foo() {
    println("recompose function")

    Box {
        println("recompose box")

        Column {
            println("recompose column")

            Row {
                println("recompose row")

                var testState by mutableStateOf("my text")

                Button(
                    onClick = { testState = "new text" }
                ) {}
                Text(testState)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

output is:
recompose function
recompose box
recompose column
recompose row

Not only does this recompose the whole function it also recreates the `testState` causing it to never change values.

Again not 100% that this is your problem, but I would look into it. The solution would be to split my `Row` and row content into it's own Composable function.

Comment: Putting the Dropdown menu in a wrapper composable worked. The performance is still bad but at least no more unwanted recompositions.

Comment: @HavanaSun can you share your solution? please.